# APIFlask app returns different errors with status code but why spec doesn't have that?

Tags: flask, openapi, apiflask

I have an APIFlask app and a GET endpoint. Everything works fine and I have the API spec `api.yaml`. I can see the responses - [image]

There are some error responses. But I am looking for some `500` response that I raised in the code -

```
if not identity:
    abort(403)
```

Is there any configuration to have those manual error responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't detect the error code you returned in your view function. It does add some status code for your endpoint automatically (401, 422, 404) based on the decorator you used. For other error responses, you have to use the `doc` decorator to add manually:

```
@app.get('/')
@app.doc(responses=[403])
def hello():
    abort(403)
```

Refer to the docs for more details: https://apiflask.com/openapi/#alternative-operation-responses

Comment: Thanks, it works. For those who wants to set schema for each status, see the documentation mentioned in the answer.